# str(int(time.time())) gives error string indices must be integers in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, time, nonce

I am new to python i create one python pip package for my site API in this i need to pass the nonce. I write the code like below

```
payload = {}
        headers = {}

        if self.api_key is not None:
            payload["api_key"] = self.api_key 

        if self.secret_key is not None:
            payload["secret_key"] = self.secret_key

            payload["request"] = method


            payload["nonce"] = str(int(time.time()))



        payload.update(kwargs)

        headers["X-WCX-APIKEY"] = self.api_key
        headers["X-WCX-PAYLOAD"] = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8'))
        headers["X-WCX-SIGNATURE"] = 'SIGNATURE'
              url = self.base_url.replace('API_CALL',method)

        # update the parameters with the API key
        session = requests.session()
        response = session.post(url, data = payload, headers = headers)
```

when run this code i got this error "string indices must be integers"

How can i fix it please help anyone

Note i import the "time"

Comment: `str(int(time.time()))` is not doing the error. Check the line causing the error, I do not see why this one would cause an error

Comment: Please post the full error message, including the line that triggered it.  Better yet, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The integer value is not converted to string that is the problem to occur this error. if i try like this str(int(time.time()))+'-test' it accepted. Anyone know what it the problem here? it may be the version problem 2.x to 3.x?